# Why is my record being deleted from the db when I attempt to update the record from entity framework MVC?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I attempt to update a record from entity framework the record is being deleted from the table. There are no errors thrown so it really has me baffled what is happening.

I am fairly new to entity framework and asp.net. I've been learning it for about a month now.

I can update the record without any issues from SQL Server but not from vs. Here is the code to update the db:

```
 // GET: /Scorecard/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, string EmployeeName)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }


        CRS_Monthly crs_monthly = GetAgentById(id);

        crs_monthly.EmployeeName = EmployeeName;

        if (crs_monthly == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(crs_monthly);
    }

    // POST: /Scorecard/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="REC_ID,Cur_Plan,Plan_Update,Comments,Areas_Improve,Strengths,UPDATED_BY,UPDATED_TIME,Agent_Recognition")] CRS_Monthly crs_monthly)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            crs_monthly.UPDATED_TIME = DateTime.Now;
            crs_monthly.UPDATED_BY = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Split('\\')[1];
            db.Entry(crs_monthly).State = EntityState.Modified;  
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(crs_monthly);
    }
```

When I run the debugger crs_monthly is valid and looks fine until db.SaveChanges(). Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, for example, if you run `SELECT COUNT(*)` before and after, there is one less record in the table? Maybe it's updated to something unexpected rather than being deleted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *never* save an instance of your entity created from a post, especially when you're utilizing `Bind` to restrict which properties are bound from the post data. Instead, always pull the entity fresh from the database and map the posted values on to it. This ensures that no data is lost.

Using `Bind` is a horrible practice, anyways. The chief problem with it is that all your properties are listed as string values, and you're introducing maintenance concerns. If remove one of these properties or change the name, the `Bind` list is not automatically updated. You must remember to change every single instance. Worse, if you add properties, you have to remember to go back and include them in this list or else your data just gets silently dropped with no notice.

If you need to only work with a subset of properties on your entity, create a view model containing just those properties. Then, again, map the posted values from your view model onto an instance of your entity pulled fresh from the database.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am teaching myself so I'm not aware of all the best practices with entity framework. I followed your advice and everything is updating properly now. I appreciate it!